# How to find the summation of the above series upto 200 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> **Q) How to find the summation of the following series upto $200$ terms?**
> $$
> S = \frac{2\sin\theta}{3} + \frac{3\sin^{2}\theta}{5} 
> + \frac{4\sin^{3}\theta}{7} + \dots 
> + \frac{201\sin^{200}\theta}{401}
> $$

Ans) Here what I have noticed is that
$$
\{2,3,4,\dots,201\}
$$
is in Arithmetic Progression. Secondly,
$$
\{\sin\theta, \sin^{2}\theta, \sin^{3}\theta, 
\dots, \sin^{200}\theta\}
$$
is in G.P. Third:
$$
\biggl\{\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{7}, 
\dots, \frac{1}{401}\biggr\}
$$
is in Harmonic Progression.

When I was in class XITh I learnt about Arithmetico-Geometrico Progression. I also learnt how to find the summation of an Arithmetico-Geometrico Progression. But I don't know how to find the summation of these types of series's. Please help me out with this above summation.

Comment: You're made the right observations. Now use all of those tricks to find the summation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! High-quality questions usually include what you've already done in trying to work the problem. If you can show us what you've been able to do, you might be able to get more help. That said, according to WolframAlpha at least, this is way more complex than it appears. The infinite sum according to WA is $$\frac{-2\sin^{3/2}\theta+\sqrt{\sin\theta}+(\sin\theta-1)\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{\sin\theta})}{2(\sin\theta-1)\sqrt{\sin\theta}}$$ The partial summations rely on something I've never heard of, the "Lerch transcendent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're made the right observations. Now use all of those tricks to find the summation.

- For an arithmetic progression, to find the sum of $a+nd$, we pair up the first and last terms.
- For a geometric progression, to find the sum of $ ar^d$, we multiply by $r$ and subtract the terms.
- For a harmonic progression, to find the sum of $ \frac{1}{a+nd}$, we first find the sum of $ x^{a+nd-1}$, integrate it, and then set $ x = 1$.

Apply these to find $S(x) = \sum \frac{1+i}{1+2i} x^{2i}$ where $ x = \sqrt{ \sin \theta }$.
To get there, we want to find $ T(x) = \sum (1+i) x^{2i}$, then integrate it.
To get that, we want to find $  (1-x^2) T(x) = ( 2x^2 - 201x^{404} )+ x^4 + x^6 + \ldots$.
To get that, we want to find $ R(x) = x^4 + x^6 +  \ldots$.
Thus, we are (theoretically) done.